# Javascript: How can I selectively convert a string of characters into their respective unicode values, add 1, and then convert back to string?

Tags: javascript, unicode

I'm able to successfully target only the letters in my string, however I am having trouble converting only the letters to their unicode values. Please help.

```
function LetterChanges(str) { 

for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
 if(str.charCodeAt(i) > 64 && str.charCodeAt(i) < 127){
  str.repalce(i, charCodeAt(i));
  }
 }
console.log(str)      
}

LetterChanges("hello*3");
```

Comment: You want only alphabetic characters? [a-z]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function LetterChanges(str) {
  var newStr = ""; // the result string
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var c = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if (c > 64 && c < 127) {
      newStr += String.fromCharCode(c + 1);
    }
    else {
      newStr += String.fromCharCode(c);
    }
  }
  return newStr;
}

console.log(LetterChanges("hello*3"));
```

If you want to replace only alphabetic characters `a-z`, you can do it using a regular expression like this:

```js
function LetterChanges(str) {
  return str.replace(/[a-z]/gi, function(m) {
    return String.fromCharCode(
      m.charCodeAt(0) + 1
    );
  });
}

console.log(LetterChanges("Hello*3"));
```

Comment: He wanted to change all the letters in the string into their unicode. I'm not sure what your code does actually...

Comment: @Kinduser what part of _convert it back to a string_ don't you understand?

Comment: Oh my Godness, he wrote what he wants in the tittle... Okey, whatever. Forget.

Comment: @Kinduser but still you could be right! The question is poorly descibed!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I appreciate your creativity.
So I was able to use this to convert to unicodes + 1:   
   str = str.replace(str.charAt(i), c + 1);
I am now trying to do the same to convert back to letters with this:
   str = str.replace(str.charAt(i), str.fromCharCode(i));

However this is not working correctly. I can see how your solution works but I would like to make my own solution work!

Comment: @ColinSygiel When transforming the characters to their unicode code on the same string the length of the string changes. Then it become impossible to change it back the way you are trying to. Example: String is `AB` (length = 2) when you change it it wil become `6566` (length = 4). Then you can't select the unicode codes because you won't be able to tell where does it start from (`6566` is the code is `65` or `56` or `66`...). Understood??

Comment: The best thing is to use another string `newStr` to generate the new string!

Answer (score 0):

I actually think this looks a lot better as a one liner.  I actually needed to do this in an interview recently and they seemed pretty impressed by the conciseness of my solution

So instead I would use this:

`function letterChange(str){
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null,Array.prototype.map.call(str,i=>i.charCodeAt(0)+1));
}`

Also not that the i=>u.charCodeAt(0) is a lambda function and will not work in all web browsers without use of a transpiler.  You could also use this if you are still using es5:

`function letterChange(str){
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null,Array.prototype.map.call(str,function(i){
        return i.charCodeAt(0)+1;
    }));
}`

To explain this a little more lets break it down:

the first thing that may raise questions is the 'apply' function.  Apply takes 2 parameters, an object (irrelevant in this case so we use null), and an array of parameters.  These parameters are then passed in comma separated form to the function that we call apply on.  In the case of fromCharCode, passing multiple parameters returns a String composed of all of the results.  Next, we are passing it 'Array.prototype.map.call' which allows us to call the array literal function map on a String which does not come with map out of the box.  We then pass this the function to apply and return the full result.

Comment: Since you're using ES6 arrow functions, you could also use `Array.from` to convert the string to an array which makes the whole thing a bit more readable: `Array.from('abc').map(c => String.fromCharCode(c.charCodeAt(0) + 1)).join('')`

Comment: Or `String.fromCharCode(...Array.from('abc').map(c => c.charCodeAt(0) + 1))`