# Javascript: How can I convert my unicode values back to characters?

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have been able to successfully convert my characters to Unicode, add 1, however I am having trouble with the final step of converting back to characters. I am not sure why the last statement in the if statement is not working. Please help!

```js
function LetterChanges(str) {
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var c = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if (c > 64 && c < 127) {
      str = str.replace(str.charAt(i), c + 1);
      str = str.replace(str.charAt(i), str.fromCharCode(i));
    }
  }
  console.log(str);
}

LetterChanges("hello*3");
```

Comment: Why are you asking essentially the same question that you just asked and got an answer to an hour ago?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: How can I selectively convert a string of characters into their respective unicode values, add 1, and then convert back to string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42331718/javascript-how-can-i-selectively-convert-a-string-of-characters-into-their-resp)

Answer (score 0):

**[`fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)** is meant to be called on the `String` object itself as a static method that you pass your instance into.

Additionally, `charAt(i)` is functionally equivalent to `[i]`.

While I'm not exactly sure what you are after here, you can see the implementation of it here:

```js
function LetterChanges(str) { 

  for(var i = 0; i < str.length; i++){
    var c = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if(c > 64 && c < 127){
      str = str.replace(str[i], String.fromCharCode(c + 1));
    }
  }
  console.log(str);      
}
       
LetterChanges("hello*3");
```

Comment: To put you on the context: here is the original question http://stackoverflow.com/q/42331718/6647153!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Hmmm. Thanks, but makes you wonder why this question was posted.

Comment: All I understood is that he wants to get the charcode at index `i`, increments it by 1 if it was between 65 & 126 and put it back as a character not a number which I thought it will be better if he accumulated the result in a new string rather than using `replace` on the original which could lead to errors (for example `"66ABC"` becomes `"B66CD"`)!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Agreed, but that wasn't the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `fromCharCode(i)`, but `i` is the index into the string, not the character code. You want to pass the character code: `String.fromCharCode(c+1)` or whatever.

Comment: Actually, he's calling `fromCharCode()` on `str`, which is the main problem. He's passing `i` into the method.